# Sharepoint 2010 List backup

Tags: 2010, list, sharepoint-server, backup

I want to backup a list in sharepoint 2010 and restore in a different site.

Am performing backup with "Granular Backup" option in Central Administration site and restoring using `Import-SPWeb http://test -path c:\ListBackup\yyy.cmp` . After i restored i can see Created By and Modfied By is changed to my name and also time is changed as of today ,for every item in the list. My requirement is to restore List as it is. It has Major and Minor versions too.